# Sending ICMPv6 Messages using Impacket (ImpactPacket and Impact Decoder)

Tags: python, packet-injection, impacket, pcapy

I can't seem to find a good documentation for sending packets on ICMPv6 Messages.

There is a sample from Impacket but it uses Ping6 so it simply calls

```
ICMP6.ICMP6.Echo_Request(1, seq_id,payload)
```

and it will return a ping message.

How should I start like for example sending an RA Message.

Also the hardest part for me is the payload, because in my sniffing and detection. Impacket does not have any module to read "objectly" the payload so it is bunch of hex and based from that we make assumptions.

Thanks for people who can help

Comment: I am not familiar with Impacket, but I like using scapy. Maybe consider using it? http://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapyipv6.html

Comment: Can't, my project I already use Impacket and I need it to use all the way. I don't have time to study another library. 
*Edit: Also I Scapy is build to use through its interactive environment, I think there are limitations on using it for python

Comment: Scapy is a Python interface to libpcap and it's interactive environment is Python, so I don't really see why there would be such limitation. Other than that I can't help you, I never used Impacket.